# Are the items/enemies you find in Bit Dungeon completely random or is there some kind of pattern?

Tags: bit-dungeon

I was playing Bit Dungeon for the third time in a row and noticed that on the first time I had gotten a weapon that was level 6 and had life-steal. It came from a green chest dropped from a zombie boss, and on the third time I faced the same enemy and got a level 3 spear that sucked.

So, I'm wondering if all the different rooms were completely randomized or if they could be predicted to some amount of certainty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the contents in game are random. You will never know what happens next room, or what loot you will get after the boss.

However these random things come with some calculations to prevent you from getting too strong early game or too weak late game.

Answer (score 3):

The game is completely randomized. You will, of course, find harder enemies and better loot deeper in the dungeon, but other than that, there is no way to predict what you will find.